# While function doesn't stop in certain circumstances

Tags: while-loop, c++17

I created a simple "minigame". It basically asks for four random numbers, then determines if you "die" according to the numbers you gave it. Letters will be treated as 0 BEFORE the first loop. When you're done the game asks you if you want to play again. Yes or no are the options, any other stuff will be treated as no. It works just fine, for the first time that is.

AFTER the first loop, when the game asks if you want to play again, every word you enter will be treated as yes. And remember that it wants numbers not letters or smth right? Once again, after the first loop, every letter or word you type, it breaks. It literally says:
"You don't have any HP.
Play again? Enter four random numbers separated by a space.

You don't have any HP.
Play again? Enter four random numbers separated by a space." All over again. The "looping system" and the loop is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()

{

    //insert stuff here

    cout << "Play again? ";

    char answer[20];

    const char *answerE = "yes";

    cin >> answer;

    int result = strcasecmp(answer, answerE);

    while (result == 0)

    {

        //insert loop here

        cout << "Play again? ";

        cin >> answer;

        int result = strcasecmp(answer, answerE);

    }

    //insert stuff here

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You have redefined the variable `result` inside the loop, which hides the variable that the loop is testing. Note that to avoid code duplication here, you can consider turning the loop into a _do-while_ instead of a _while_ construct.

Comment: Unrelated, but as a public service please avoid adding a blank line between _every_ line. Contrary to what you might think, it is quite difficult to read. While there is no real "rule", code lines should generally be organized into logical groups of multiple lines that perform some task. Often there is a comment above that group of lines describing the group does. The groups themselves are separated by a blank line.

Comment: Remove `int` before `result` inside the loop.

Comment: @paddy how? it just says "use of unclarified identifier" smth like that. the code is: `#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
  do
  {
   cout << "play again";
   char answer[20];
   const char * answerE = "yes";
  
   cin >> answer;
  
   int result = strcasecmp(answer, answerE);
  }
  while(result == 0)
 
  return 0;
 }`

Comment: `int result = ...` _defines_ a variable. `result = ...` _assigns_ a new value. You have a copy/paste error in the version that appears in the loop, because you redefined it. Remove the `int`. Regarding the shortened loop you just posted (as a comment, eww), the problem is that `result` is not visible in the `while` part. You should define `int result;` _before_ the loop, and once again do not redefine it in the loop.